# Rambam and Mitzvas Talmud Torah

Tags: torah-study, rambam, mitzvah

As opposed to other Codifiers of Halacha (e.g. Shulchan Aruch Harav see Hilchos Talmud Torah 1:1, 2:1 and the Kuntres Acharon there) the Rambam famously doesn't provide the reasons for the Mitzvahs and Halochos in his Mishneh Torah (See also Tshuvos Harosh 31:9).

This apparently correlates with his opinion that the Mitzvah of Yedias Hatorah "...ולמדתם אותם" does not include the reasons of the halochos and just necessitates the knowledge of the final halacha (explicit in the above Kuntres Acharon and I recall but can't remember the Rambam mentioning this).

Does anyone have sources within the Rambam or from others backing this up from any Gemoro or other Rishonim or any sources discussing Rambam's opinion?

Comment: Two examples that come to mind where the Rambam brings the reason behind a *mitzvah* is [Shofar](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.3.4) and [Tumah/Tahara](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Immersion_Pools.11.12?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

Comment: @robev I've edited it, I hope it's clearer

Comment: You're correct in that, but he definitely doesn't systematically include טעמי המצוות in his code.

Comment: Well, the Rashba was against studying the reasoning behind mitzvos. Seemingly he would agree the mitzvah of ולמדתם אותם precludes them.

Comment: Note: I think the concept of "Yediyas HaTorah" is from the Achronim so I don't expect you to find any gemarra or rishonim explicitly discussing it. You may find support for what you're looking for though.

Comment: See [Rav Asher Weiss](https://www.torahbase.org/%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95-%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/) on Yediyas HaTorah (section 6)

Comment: https://hakirah.org/Vol%209%20Shapiro.pdf  A full essay analyzing the Rambam position on this very topic

Comment: Thank you @Chatzkel